# Cant open file make sure xfin42c8 - document library is running on your PC error on accesing sharepoint document stored on the onedrive from local

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, onedrive-for-business, microsoft

I Can't open file. Getting below error on accesing SharePoint document stored on the onedrive from local:

> Make sure xfin42c8 - document library is running on your PC.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below tips to troubleshoot the issue.

1.Make sure you have logged in OneDrive with your account.

2.Turn off Files On-Demand feature.

3.Quit OneDrive then start it again from the Start Menu.

4.Reinstall OneDrive